# How to disable ctrl-z, ctrl-c from breaking out of a php script

Tags: php, signals

Can someone point me in the correct direction for researching how to prevent users from breaking out of a php script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: Do you mean on the command line?

Comment: Yes, will be a command line script running that I don't want users to be able to break out of, essentially.  Sorry for the shoddy details in the post, still waking up.

Answer (score 20):

If you have php compiled with [PCNTL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) (Process Control) and are not running Windows you can use [`pcntl_signal()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php).

There is an example [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/1) which I modified, and it seems to catch Ctrl-C ok:

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1);

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "signal_handler");

function signal_handler($signal) {
    switch($signal) {
        case SIGINT:
            print "Ctrl C\n";
    }
}

while(1) {

}
```

If you try to install a handler for `SIGSTP` nothing happens, but I don't know why.

Comment: Additionally SIGTSTP is for Ctrl+Z

Comment: SIGSTP and SIGSTOP are different signals :)

Comment: @silent: thanks. i clearly don't really know what i'm talking about here

Comment: The example with the empty loop didn't work for me, Ctrl+C was ignored. When adding a usleep(1); or a echo '1'; it worked.

Comment: This is neat. One can also define the handler as callback instead of a separate function. It's important to declare the `ticks`, without the declaration the signal is caught but the handler is not executed, i.e. you get stuck in your script.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do it by having disabled in the shell.

[Source](http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/12605-shell-script-disable-ctrl-c-ctrl-z.html) is here.

```
#!/bin/bash
# at start add
trap "" 2 20

# your script 
echo " Test"

# loop for sleep
sleep 5
```

20 is for CTRL + Z

2 is for CTRL  + C

and this is the full list of created by the trap -| command

```
1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL
5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE
9) SIGKILL      10) SIGUSR1     11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM     16) SIGSTKFLT
17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ     26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR      31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN
35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3  38) SIGRTMIN+4
39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12
47) SIGRTMIN+13 48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14
51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12 53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10
55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7  58) SIGRTMAX-6
59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

however to do this straight from PHP is difficult, I am not sure how to do it or if it can be done. otherwise some sites suggested javascript to capture keystrokes. hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function. Set this in php.ini *ignore_user_abort* to true. If changed to TRUE scripts will not be terminated after a client has aborted their connection, so the script will finish.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

or

```
$ php my_script.php -d ignore_user_abort = true
```

Comment: ctrl+z will freeze it anyway, though

Comment: @teksolo and @silent I never tested it, but it will be nice to know if it behaves

Comment: This is for web interactions.  However, in a comment, the OP says he wants this for a command line script.

Comment: tis not just for web, you can look the documentation

Comment: @silent:  Okay, after re-reading the online documentation, it is not for just the web.  However, *it is for client-server interactions* (which, it seems to me, are usually via the web when using PHP).  It doesn't work for command line scripts (at least it didn't for me).

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it in background (add & to the end of command):

```
./your_php_script &
```

Comment: What if the script requires user interaction?

Comment: Of course, my solution isn't usable for scripts that requires any interaction

Answer (score 0):

If you use the numeric values (rather than the built-in PHP constants) then it seems to work, at least for me, on a Debian/Ubuntu system.

Oddly enough, in my example below, the callback function signal_handler() is not being called. Instead, it just displays "^Z" and "^C" on the input line, while the signals are simply being ignored. In the end, no break/suspend is possible, which hopefully answers the original question:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
pcntl_signal( 2, "signal_handler");
pcntl_signal( 20, "signal_handler");

function signal_handler( $signal )
{
  echo( "This is not even invoked..?\n" );
}

$end = FALSE;

while( $end == FALSE )
{
  echo( "Enter Q to quit: " );
  $fp = fopen( "php://stdin", "r" );
  $line = fgets( $fp ); 
  $line = str_replace( "\n", "", $line );
  fclose( $fp );

  if( strtolower($line) == "q" ) $end = TRUE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need your script to ignore a specific signal, use the SIG_IGN constant option. For SIGINT signal the code would be

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

Answer (score -2):

If feasible, you can wrap the main loop in a try-catch block, and squash the Abort/Interrupt exception (not sure the exact one, sorry, my PHP is a bit rusty)

Comment: While short on details, this answer's approach seems the only one for a command line script, so I don't get the downvote.

Comment: because there's no abort/interrupt exception in PHP