# PHP PCNTL - Maintain control in terminal

Tags: php, terminal, pcntl

I want to run parallel processes to process at least 4 users simultaneously.

```
ob_end_flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
   $pid=pcntl_fork();
   if ($pid == -1) {
      echo("Could not create a new child.");
      exit;
   } else if ($pid == 0) {
      //This will get excuted only in the child process
      echo 'parent1';
      sleep(5);
      echo 'parent2';
     exit;
   }
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
> php testscript.php
parent1
parent1
parent1
parent1
> parent2
parent2
parent2
parent2
```

What is currently happening is after displaying `parent1` 4 times the control on the script is lost, and a new empty command line is started. After waiting for 5 more seconds the remaining output comes.

How can i avoid that from happening. I want to be able to break the script as and when I want.

**EDIT**

If i send a signal via terminal say by pressing CTRL+C, the script does not stops, need a way to inform the script to stop at that instant.

Comment: How are your brainwaves of "wanting" transferred to the PHP script? I didn't know a library exists for brainwaves. Can you elaborate, looks like a very cool extension everybody should know about.

Comment: modified the question. requirement is to make the php script listen to the signal sent from the terminal post sleep.

Comment: Like in [How to disable ctrl-z, ctrl-c from breaking out of a php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774331/how-to-disable-ctrl-z-ctrl-c-from-breaking-out-of-a-php-script) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating dirty zombie/parent-less processes who're being adopted by others who certainly don't want them either =)

When you're working with forking you need to understand you're creating a copy of the current process (stack/heap and all), giving it a new process id (PID) and setting it's parent id (PPID) as its own as to say the spawned process is a child. Here the parent of these 4 new children finished all his apparent work then died without any error because he has nothing left to do.. But as any respectful parent should do, your parent process should sit around and take care of his children. That's where signals can become useful especially the SIGCHLD signal, which will be sent to any parent process whos child just past away. Combining that with a small event handling loop and your parent can gracefully manage his children \o/

tl;dr I have a an example fork wrapper sitting in my blog http://codehackit.blogspot.be/2012/01/childpids-break-pcntlsignaldispatch.html

Comment: Using your code in the blog, each process is waiting for the previous process to finish first. My requirement is to run these processes independent of the previous child been finished or not.

Comment: That's simply not true. Please post an example of how you're using it, maybe there's a client error.

Comment: yes, indeed, it was a mistake in my implementation, works great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) to set up a signal handler for CTRL-C(which equals to [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29), with a value of 2) if you want to react on it in a custom fashion.

Comment: Tried that, but in vain. As after showing parent1 the fourth time, a new terminal line is started, hence pressing CTRL-C after that is not sending any signal to the PHP script.